# Ajax call in onChange function stops sliding animation of slider bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to implement the jRange slider (https://github.com/nitinhayaran/jRange) in my Ruby on Rails project. To send data to my controller, I included an ajax call in my onchange function but this seems to result in a refresh when and my slider reverts to the original value. I am still able to access the value in controller via params[:data_value] though. How does the ajax call actually affects my change event?

Here are my codes:-

```
// html
<input type="hidden" class="slider-input" value="1" />

// js.erb
$('.slider-input').jRange({
    from: 0,
    to: 10.0,
    step: 1,
    scale: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    format: '%s',
    width: 800,
    showLabels: true,
    snap: true,
    theme: 'theme-blue',
    onstatechange: function(value) {
        var array = value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/users/registrations/capability/edit",
            data: {
                data_value: array
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is in your controller and in the results of what you're fetching with your ajax call.

Do you return json/js output in controller's action?
Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Hey sorry turns out I should just include it in a rails form to submit. Sorry for the confusion!